# Git asks a password for a wrong URL every-time, whenever I tried to excute git clone,git pull

Tags: git, macos, ssh, terminal, git-config

Git asks a password for a wrong URL every-time, whenever I tried to excute git clone,git pull.

password asked in the following format without any username.

Password for 'http://xxxxxxxxx@192.168.0.23:8080':

Git config

```
[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 ignorecase = true
 precomposeunicode = true

[user]
 name = manishk

[remote "origin"]
 url = http://xxx.0.23:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/202006-015-ping/_git/… 
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Can you also post what is shown in `git remote -v`

Comment: it gives two url for fetch and push,not related to the above given url@KarthikNayak

Comment: Are these `http` URLs or `ssh` URLs? can you show us your `.git/config` ?

Comment: [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 ignorecase = true
 precomposeunicode = true
[user]
 name = manishk
[remote "origin"]
 url = http://xxx.xxx.0.23:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/202006-015-ping/_git/ios/
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*@KarthikNayak

Comment: those are http urls@KarthikNayak

Answer (score 0):

From your git config, it looks like it's calling the URL as specified.

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs are malformed.  If you want to use a URL with a port number, you need to specify the scheme.  So if you intended this to be an HTTP URL, you'd write this:

```
$ git remote set-url http://xxx.xxx.0.23:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/202006-015-ping/_git/
```

and if this were to be an SSH URL, you'd write this:

```
$ git remote set-url ssh://xxx.xxx.0.23:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/202006-015-ping/_git/
```

If you want to use SSH keys, then you must use an SSH URL.  If you use an HTTP or HTTPS URL, then a password is typically required.  If you don't want to be prompted for the same password every time, you can set up a credential helper by running `git config credential.helper osxkeychain` (for macOS).  That will result in your password being saved the next to you're prompted for it.

Note, of course, that sending any sort of credentials across a plain HTTP (that is, non-HTTPS, non-SSH) connection is insecure, so you should avoid doing that.

Comment: I  tried this  $ git remote set-url http://xxx.xxx.0.23:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/202006-015-ping/_git/.       but again it is asking for password for wrong url different from above like this. "http://xxxxxxxxx@192.168.0.23:8080".   @bk2204

Comment: Your URL needs to have a scheme (that is, either `http://`, `https://`, or `ssh://`).  It will prompt you with your username in the URL; that's normal and expected.  It's showing you the username for whose password you're being prompted so that if you have multiple accounts, you can put the right credentials in.

Comment: sorry but, it is there http://     and also it is not asking for username first ,it directly asking for password of any random wrong url.@bk2204